# apache error: No such host is known

Tags: apache2

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
ServerName dummy-host.example.com
ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/nmb48/public/"
ServerName nmb48.local
<Directory C:/wamp/www/nmb48/public/>
AllowOverride All
Order Deny,Allow   
Allow from all 
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache error:

```
[Wed Dec 04 16:47:51.919206 2013] [core:error] [pid 15872:tid 348] (OS 11001)No such host is known.  : AH00547: Could not resolve host name *: -- ignoring!
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
[Wed Dec 04 16:47:54.169335 2013] [core:error] [pid 15872:tid 348] (OS 11001)No such host is known.  : AH00547: Could not resolve host name *: -- ignoring!
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
[Wed Dec 04 16:47:54.193336 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 15872:tid 348] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.4.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Dec 04 16:47:54.193336 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 15872:tid 348] AH00456: Server built: Feb 22 2013 22:08:37
[Wed Dec 04 16:47:54.193336 2013] [core:notice] [pid 15872:tid 348] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'
[Wed Dec 04 16:47:54.194336 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 15872:tid 348] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 15972
[Wed Dec 04 16:47:56.903491 2013] [core:error] [pid 15972:tid 240] (OS 11001)No such host is known.  : AH00547: Could not resolve host name *: -- ignoring!
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
[Wed Dec 04 16:47:59.154620 2013] [core:error] [pid 15972:tid 240] (OS 11001)No such host is known.  : AH00547: Could not resolve host name *: -- ignoring!
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
[Wed Dec 04 16:48:01.428750 2013] [core:error] [pid 15972:tid 240] (OS 11001)No such host is known.  : AH00547: Could not resolve host name *: -- ignoring!
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
[Wed Dec 04 16:48:03.678878 2013] [core:error] [pid 15972:tid 240] (OS 11001)No such host is known.  : AH00547: Could not resolve host name *: -- ignoring!
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
[Wed Dec 04 16:48:03.699880 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 15972:tid 240] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Do i change or remove the virtualhosts 80 ?

---

i already remove virtualhost *:80 and add

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/nmb48/public/"
        ServerName nmb48.local

<Directory C:/wamp/www/nmb48/public/>
AllowOverride All
Order Deny,Allow   
Allow from all 
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

new error:

```
[Thu Dec 05 10:00:43.523014 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5404:tid 392] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.4.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Dec 05 10:00:43.523014 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5404:tid 392] AH00456: Server built: Feb 22 2013 22:08:37
[Thu Dec 05 10:00:43.523014 2013] [core:notice] [pid 5404:tid 392] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'
[Thu Dec 05 10:00:43.525014 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5404:tid 392] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4552
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:1
[Thu Dec 05 10:00:44.218054 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4552:tid 284] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: "No such host is known Could not resolve host name" Look you have first to resolve your server name here because the physical server name maybe is not the same with the servername you define in the virtualhost

Answer (score 2):

Add it in the beginning of your file :

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

And remove those lines :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
ServerName dummy-host.example.com
ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

These are examples provided by apache, they should be deleted or commented.

Comment: do i comment the serverroot also? ServerRoot "C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.4"

Comment: Visibly you can now remove `NameVirtualHost *:80`. The rest of your errors are only notices, everything must be OK now.